# How to match output from MD5 hash of Unicode string in C#, in a Ruby application?

Tags: c#, ruby, unicode

Here is code fragment of c#.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes('test');
byte[] numArray = new byte[0];
numArray = (byte[])null;
using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
numArray = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);
```

OutPut:

```
bytes = [116, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0] 
numArray = [200, 5, 158, 46, 199, 65, 159, 89, 14, 121, 215, 241, 183, 116, 191, 230]
```

Above same thing trying to achieve using Ruby or Ruby on Rails but facing some issues -

ruby code

```
bytes = "test".bytes.to_a.join(",") + ","
bytes = bytes.gsub(",", "/0/").split("/")
numArray = Digest::MD5.digest(bytes)
```

OutPut:

```
bytes = ["116", "0", "101", "0", "115", "0", "116", "0"]
```

When I am trying to access Digest::MD5.digest it is accepting only string value if I convert it into string I could not get same the result as C# code provided.

Comment: Could you clarify "find ready code in C#"? Do you have a need to match output from the C# example? I have assumed that is the case in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works in Ruby 1.9.3 and higher:

```
require 'digest/md5'
Digest::MD5.digest( "test".encode( 'UTF-16LE' ) ).bytes.to_a
 => [200, 5, 158, 46, 199, 65, 159, 89, 14, 121, 215, 241, 183, 116, 191, 230]
```

Some explanation:

- C# (and Microsoft code in general) defaults to UTF-16LE for Unicode strings
- Your string-mangling with inserting commas and `gsub` will get you in trouble, use Ruby's String encoding methods.
- `Digest::MD5.digest` will read input strings as if force-encoded to 'ASCII-8BIT' (i.e. it just reads the bytes in the string, as they are stored, ignoring the character semantics), and also returns data in that encoding.

Comment: `bytes` is a shorthand for `each_byte.to_a` so it's already an array. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-bytes

Comment: @j03w: Interesting. That's a change from 1.9.3 - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-bytes (returns an Enumerator) - my code works in both, but the `.to_a` is redundant in 2.0.0

Comment: Thank you very much Neil this is exactly I want. Thanks a lot.